# ssh to compute engine keeps asking for a paraphrase

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Just added a new machine on google cloud and ran the google config.

While I can successfully connect to the machine, any attempt to log in via ssh keeps prompting me for paraphrase. Even more, it happens on my other instances too.

Not sure why.

I tried:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add
```

But that made no difference.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

made a mistake with a private key (added the wrong one!).

Ran `ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` and problem was solved.